# Iterative SQL Delete Statement

Tags: sql-server

The following is a simple version of a delete I need to perform.

```
delete from table_name
where order_date < (getdate()-60)
go
```

This is deleting a large number of blobs and to clean up the table I need to reduce the number of days in small chunks to avoid TEMPDB filling up.

Is there an easy way of getting this to run in passes each time reducing the number of days by 1 starting at say 60 days and ending at 30 days?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Do you have to delete in day chunks? Would it be acceptable to simply delete the top N rows, in batches where the dates fall between >= getdate()-60 and <= getdate()-30

Comment: Please don't use `GETDATE()-60`, use `DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())`

Comment: Why not just use a loop and delete n rows each time until you're done? This is simpler than doing one day at a time, and should be more predictable in terms of how long each iteration takes and how much log is used regardless of data distribution. See http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the amount of data being deleted, and if you are in the full or bulk-logged recovery model. Then you might want to look into adjusting the TOP N value and/or increasing your t-log backup frequency.

```
DECLARE @MinDate    DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,-60, GETDATE())
        ,@Maxdate   DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,-30, GETDATE())
        ,@RowCount  INT = 1

WHILE   @RowCount > 0

BEGIN 

        DELETE  TOP (20000)
                tn
        FROM    table_name tn
        WHERE   order_date >= @MinDate
        AND     order_date <= @Maxdate

        SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT   

    RAISERROR('%d rows deleted', 10, 0, @RowCount) WITH NOWAIT

END
```